# Splitting feature says invalid geometry but Check Validity says its valid?

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting

I am trying to split features in a shape file but I got an error message. I've had cases in other shape files where the message also appear. I then run the "Check Validity" option and rearrange the nodes and it solves the problem. However, this time, the outputs indicates that the geometry is valid and it can't split a feature. Could you please let me know how to solve the problem?

Please find below a picture of the polygon and the wkt geometry (3857):

```
Polygon ((-1478124.78303052391856909 946979.19179310125764459, -1478124.78299272269941866 946979.19176419556606561, -1478117.26708274846896529 946975.51689762540627271, -1478124.13677314156666398 946978.9996919083641842, -1478124.78299656976014376 946979.1918028024956584, -1478125.42911988170817494 946979.38391370442695916, -1478126.39029588829725981 946981.93328004481736571, -1478133.00600195629522204 946998.11715949547942728, -1478116.19418166764080524 947019.5813663910375908, -1478096.71958048059605062 947038.34135105996392667, -1478087.29873415036126971 947051.76140064850915223, -1478077.81862146849744022 947068.13387488957960159, -1478076.87276261090300977 947067.94267455802764744, -1478071.19821013463661075 947077.98074371041730046, -1478068.47005605162121356 947090.08436683926265687, -1478056.9928076455835253 947114.93800050253048539, -1478051.55742290639318526 947134.4337794678285718, -1478036.78718810528516769 947147.8297689949395135, -1478036.24287877208553255 947147.41335839906241745, -1478035.24045659229159355 947148.56036007427610457, -1478028.47518308600410819 947154.18423158209770918, -1478010.43498766887933016 947169.12734413566067815, -1478003.51193753606639802 947174.39229928329586983, -1477996.18103083036839962 947185.3150386696215719, -1477986.6453559456858784 947187.45741944201290607, -1477986.16662001563236117 947189.15180930169299245, -1477979.52068009995855391 947192.00959937949664891, -1477956.72736372356303036 947205.1006366804940626, -1477941.98676209547556937 947211.76584720483515412, -1477926.51834570220671594 947201.46559223323129117, -1477924.63183381408452988 947204.68807182495947927, -1477913.84756116499193013 947224.02518122468609363, -1477918.35540755442343652 947232.93035197246354073, -1477931.41642895014956594 947243.2198853122536093, -1477935.05790546699427068 947266.66019576473627239, -1477934.7642767543438822 947272.58217030973173678, -1477934.41678775497712195 947273.45011663273908198, -1477924.75737435114569962 947297.57690588745754212, -1477918.58656632993370295 947301.85732627601828426, -1477911.92580982903018594 947295.9041724952403456, -1477886.5633173396345228 947285.02128518198151141, -1477883.52481583342887461 947289.86700836394447833, -1477883.36824055877514184 947289.6473647216334939, -1477882.26180193177424371 947292.16274000389967114, -1477872.75556000182405114 947312.79801348550245166, -1477864.11568794469349086 947331.06792474305257201, -1477904.25632409169338644 947351.06341518892440945, -1477934.21285946317948401 947399.87632608832791448, -1477935.62233732268214226 947402.14503821777179837, -1477941.86192234070040286 947412.18794218730181456, -1477956.725561702856794 947438.3169130269670859, -1477958.22313819453120232 947439.43274707754608244, -1477958.31343927816487849 947440.07214510801713914, -1477981.0166547978296876 947461.68809562956448644, -1478008.67752024298533797 947497.35159842344000936, -1478008.48680674214847386 947497.35848130052909255, -1478013.79494903981685638 947501.4669507765211165, -1478023.70864710304886103 947534.03582140512298793, -1478023.95592392329126596 947535.23809881892520934, -1478029.7840483186300844 947563.57199546927586198, -1478025.9068078740965575 947569.37042235548142344, -1478008.12840552208945155 947573.38355044240597636, -1478006.53432100312784314 947572.73342123569454998, -1477995.80250707943923771 947573.47576088889036328, -1477962.0899669798091054 947575.74832844687625766, -1477962.87704809429123998 947579.25202215486206114, -1477963.68174892826937139 947580.93610302940942347, -1477967.64768867380917072 947589.23534927563741803, -1477977.17114987852983177 947613.24064940866082907, -1477984.02482234570197761 947630.32055377587676048, -1477983.6184674424584955 947630.77715298940893263, -1477985.84325802512466908 947637.07429530529771, -1477987.11848560115322471 947651.21521074755582958, -1477984.35018657799810171 947672.40584265254437923, -1477986.27464094059541821 947690.92510750389192253, -1477969.58415648713707924 947684.79243853606749326, -1477958.18829918885603547 947691.1361495538149029, -1477941.75039749313145876 947703.51526058558374643, -1477921.21130464295856655 947717.49232375714927912, -1477920.6228458802215755 947717.89274719136301428, -1477908.85106775863096118 947733.65836015332024544, -1477902.4198682364076376 947751.4670913954032585, -1477896.39872776134870946 947752.11317451135255396, -1477882.02934170234948397 947750.36622975813224912, -1477864.3134092902764678 947749.27741324552334845, -1477852.26822509197518229 947751.2428905371343717, -1477841.81822665967047215 947753.96842405060306191, -1477841.6534421828109771 947754.21337488852441311, -1477820.00420657056383789 947756.48888731026090682, -1477810.5363075602799654 947757.4840760852675885, -1477773.86545572732575238 947733.08798935275990516, -1477746.10738146398216486 947734.64666548720560968, -1477751.10467577166855335 947738.70768564904574305, -1477769.71220629545859993 947765.04232911660801619, -1477756.60883750207722187 947779.45546541234944016, -1477757.09137768624350429 947788.39040782023221254, -1477761.54236042173579335 947797.98823830625042319, -1477760.05039021046832204 947801.27453060995321721, -1477760.31658820691518486 947801.27453060995321721, -1477764.11754325474612415 947820.54894821555353701, -1477768.05985654680989683 947836.38474375440273434, -1477774.6695558896753937 947853.91516343445982784, -1477775.64144389005377889 947860.98727554932702333, -1477766.93359573185443878 947864.31395926559343934, -1477751.87914276099763811 947866.26587835571262985, -1477726.13752585160546005 947865.47768119082320482, -1477709.05460207094438374 947872.46892070560716093, -1477693.63023499352857471 947882.49654851970262825, -1477682.22086256975308061 947891.86908488825429231, -1477684.54636588995344937 947895.24506497173570096, -1477690.5704096129629761 947902.23762515932321548, -1477728.93385625118389726 947902.57934288156684488, -1477743.6943801804445684 947908.88776016689371318, -1477749.00822886358946562 947916.98898233915679157, -1477750.94299477525055408 947933.15236039739102125, -1477738.18130847415886819 947945.88439295464195311, -1477736.12470617727376521 947957.31818368006497622, -1477736.06824296852573752 947970.10710892616771162, -1477737.3492770460434258 947982.90200992627069354, -1477731.96995506761595607 947989.60904293216299266, -1477731.2685698929708451 947997.01024321676231921, -1477732.60286359139718115 948001.65259411034639925, -1477734.56155628245323896 948008.46793537598568946, -1477747.19249621103517711 948025.35233762802090496, -1477751.80195634951815009 948041.5277001679642126, -1477753.51417312165722251 948048.19759451446589082, -1477755.08903612988069654 948054.33152966934721917, -1477745.69451927696354687 948061.6938725303625688, -1477740.95421265531331301 948075.13498980447184294, -1477740.77491193357855082 948076.04171954118646681, -1477736.16635279823094606 948099.34573300182819366, -1477736.71917166258208454 948125.59982241597026587, -1477739.30776951601728797 948145.13168655557092279, -1477731.87775185285136104 948161.92646099778357893, -1477710.43785057496279478 948171.25411612715106457, -1477708.80292032496072352 948175.4770286314887926, -1477707.05576443392783403 948179.98953298130072653, -1477699.69122006907127798 948181.97598246077541262, -1477695.06393997557461262 948169.83905589219648391, -1477684.37066920660436153 948168.44504953315481544, -1477665.61747561488300562 948175.09229010925628245, -1477637.52332511986605823 948176.98581908864434808, -1477635.54160664998926222 948179.4566078195348382, -1477635.71810423443093896 948180.14571598079055548, -1477627.87262147082947195 948178.44652993394993246, -1477624.78176135267131031 948176.82892755116336048, -1477615.35941333347000182 948176.7867186670191586, -1477603.9781724049244076 948179.76482379250228405, -1477606.641053416300565 948182.46912805165629834, -1477624.02421329799108207 948183.2201831229031086, -1477631.68899377528578043 948188.97597812174353749, -1477631.62201879941858351 948204.12077566550578922, -1477616.51981236925348639 948216.84246234328020364, -1477613.03210799256339669 948249.47311030537821352, -1477612.59211543528363109 948273.36682710936293006, -1477615.5686475713737309 948280.78437250014394522, -1477628.18006564327515662 948302.04414305242244154, -1477640.4633163430262357 948321.95617060828953981, -1477641.20764960092492402 948323.66265018924605101, -1477644.43536292156204581 948331.06107350531965494, -1477650.62879627104848623 948367.10072140430565923, -1477653.84289434738457203 948396.39585046272259206, -1477641.43780725682154298 948404.08124741644132882, -1477635.8297291926573962 948386.89151637477334589, -1477623.44836866040714085 948389.19206364522688091, -1477623.10057932115159929 948397.90636938891839236, -1477623.60714641213417053 948398.32137493183836341, -1477623.00727486773394048 948413.35510530020110309, -1477599.59726812550798059 948444.75232162652537227, -1477567.47821187600493431 948449.45494709932245314, -1477548.86847888678312302 948484.10462483030278236, -1477558.46211865800432861 948492.22498438612092286, -1477538.28332915063947439 948518.79026385315228254, -1477505.25105058355256915 948548.52884469053242356, -1477502.49276277492754161 948551.78573868540115654, -1477465.72410144377499819 948595.20106200478039682, -1477434.22163544944487512 948641.9092633492546156, -1477435.76576405460946262 948655.64794977486599237, -1477449.0462311040610075 948737.29012502159457654, -1477490.65551135502755642 948764.13249782507773489, -1477487.39566205814480782 948775.42641416622791439, -1477476.07568971184082329 948794.76169566949829459, -1477481.56403373484499753 948823.86529931100085378, -1477480.48542626877315342 948842.88144983048550785, -1477480.11851552617736161 948849.34882159158587456, -1477440.36220962577499449 948840.52895156294107437, -1477395.5116008180193603 948831.15843630849849433, -1477367.63179026893340051 948824.8351059784181416, -1477355.2421204352285713 948822.02508589718490839, -1477354.53713122778572142 948821.63426830130629241, -1477353.47644382133148611 948821.62465223099570721, -1477331.9011910215485841 948816.73128428414929658, -1477325.49341772613115609 948815.27794105396606028, -1477311.35659200721420348 948812.07173932844307274, -1477214.49595966213382781 948788.75063986761961132, -1477168.11854163999669254 948762.17760275118052959, -1477151.87645915290340781 948734.61959407047834247, -1477146.28800305561162531 948700.52764872217085212, -1477145.04421067330986261 948700.49738347413949668, -1477146.5582055386621505 948692.33194117888342589, -1477146.91140093165449798 948692.06977735192049295, -1477146.97927691950462759 948685.43895635660737753, -1477146.986785325454548 948684.70034279848914593, -1477149.89033575728535652 948679.73775484669022262, -1477171.78764908527955413 948649.00519023730885237, -1477188.98600208922289312 948626.88446216436568648, -1477196.91868246486410499 948620.64436571905389428, -1477200.2370973255019635 948616.83570879872422665, -1477221.09925183444283903 948587.28737700264900923, -1477225.8887134799733758 948572.67567882721778005, -1477229.89459794200956821 948560.04154498944990337, -1477231.02816693368367851 948559.34635749086737633, -1477239.28851412329822779 948562.42631755908951163, -1477244.67474382999353111 948552.49317383032757789, -1477252.72125164070166647 948536.86765597842168063, -1477254.07847100170329213 948534.23236238874960691, -1477256.42149394238367677 948529.68236921273637563, -1477265.87848073220811784 948511.31781575246714056, -1477277.68049270426854491 948488.8212230980861932, -1477294.41352479322813451 948446.92168958729598671, -1477294.51563910371623933 948445.79014028387609869, -1477294.14592522382736206 948442.09678946272470057, -1477294.44656177540309727 948441.3107074381550774, -1477294.04821583908051252 948441.12081690446939319, -1477292.66456688987091184 948427.29798288724850863, -1477288.81035222136415541 948410.28244376310613006, -1477286.45851942105218768 948404.78817404096480459, -1477286.27781712892465293 948403.66087711276486516, -1477285.97557878331281245 948403.65986490668728948, -1477285.41925599961541593 948402.36008763266727328, -1477277.10514862509444356 948392.22595610015559942, -1477239.77886305609717965 948364.79703746607992798, -1477217.14142117206938565 948342.48261719802394509, -1477197.90428582043386996 948307.39416028244886547, -1477157.3839245846029371 948291.28641482908278704, -1477157.32415767456404865 948291.18671252555213869, -1477157.31284501450136304 948291.16768305434379727, -1477151.25506352144293487 948281.04876067978329957, -1477151.25035825301893055 948281.04096669307909906, -1477151.01839858456514776 948280.65339305636007339, -1477149.91676533967256546 948278.81320278020575643, -1477148.30566176422871649 948276.12194995174650103, -1477148.06329043628647923 948275.71716885955538601, -1477147.53369757207110524 948274.83250101981684566, -1477146.40203070896677673 948272.94200436829123646, -1477145.83009043871425092 948271.88941165967844427, -1477145.82868886878713965 948271.87594932038336992, -1477145.82378337625414133 948271.87311514560133219, -1477142.67716084001585841 948263.85118337580934167, -1477141.53838601591996849 948260.471935442998074, -1477139.99846211820840836 948257.02193463093135506, -1477139.1129708425141871 948254.76451433904003352, -1477137.89200400956906378 948251.651679533184506, -1477135.95843944698572159 948246.72234163817483932, -1477135.49261797056533396 948245.53502507321536541, -1477133.69770863140001893 948240.95914985332638025, -1477132.0584735635202378 948236.37325428775511682, -1477129.72155745583586395 948227.99887944501824677, -1477127.77808179776184261 948221.03440583986230195, -1477127.53961484297178686 948218.93134860543068498, -1477125.13482275325804949 948211.79500418319366872, -1477092.25040972279384732 948130.7795653595821932, -1477078.06482942216098309 948106.15329571161419153, -1477075.42257149703800678 948101.56640225311275572, -1477049.94094564067199826 948091.37069817760493606, -1477015.4001783668063581 948077.55020286596845835, -1477013.65502472617663443 948076.21551447070669383, -1477004.44371296255849302 948073.36981237214058638, -1476980.92057957337237895 948065.16136883234139532, -1476979.72383986273780465 948064.74383598554413766, -1476970.39830021909438074 948061.48961041797883809, -1476967.49194665276445448 948060.88026556535623968, -1476946.34777643671259284 948054.54409179731737822, -1476944.61123243207111955 948054.02361825061962008, -1476924.61765026394277811 948047.97450553497765213, -1476917.04447233839891851 948045.66759956127498299, -1476909.76412222418002784 948043.44986856915056705, -1476907.74115757551044226 948042.83364100172184408, -1476902.15150013496167958 948041.13101887272205204, -1476890.48884417116641998 948037.57839846482966095, -1476871.98583064740523696 948031.94216445414349437, -1476863.05182931665331125 948029.40245333209168166, -1476847.31621380150318146 948026.11138635303359479, -1476836.39438717323355377 948024.07453647791408002, -1476834.73813305166549981 948023.43897617538459599, -1476828.08408405561931431 948023.04421822621952742, -1476791.98246946604922414 948018.56806823657825589, -1476767.76435807789675891 948012.97809422411955893, -1476765.01317821885459125 948012.3430401876103133, -1476751.93593867053277791 948011.18123749014921486, -1476752.12074555386789143 948011.10572740330826491, -1476741.6766537306830287 948010.40649993566330522, -1476795.39518989669159055 947993.93396736541762948, -1476805.9167684658896178 947989.80986323126126081, -1476808.69267600541934371 947988.72174923168495297, -1476815.12627821136265993 947986.19995656935498118, -1476817.40322718513198197 947985.78971231880132109, -1476864.60346632753498852 947965.6783353069331497, -1476864.5472033426631242 947965.55788367975037545, -1476882.88343015336431563 947957.33974350779317319, -1476898.2403216992970556 947950.39636723813600838, -1476910.03602660866454244 947945.06319668551441282, -1476919.22751618130132556 947940.9074154153931886, -1476922.04587124311365187 947939.62941431603394449, -1476929.11878914292901754 947935.37737355579156429, -1476933.93648239434696734 947932.48117207083851099, -1476938.02495931019075215 947930.02315114729572088, -1476940.56550337257795036 947928.49594730930402875, -1476956.6126676513813436 947918.8487938407342881, -1476959.32450346578843892 947917.21854870277456939, -1476962.58555410313419998 947915.25812485790811479, -1476999.59878922766074538 947876.21536316105630249, -1477000.48998688859865069 947875.27533635741565377, -1477007.76573185343295336 947867.60066148929763585, -1477013.83732880931347609 947861.19619281659834087, -1477014.54181746416725218 947860.37813596217893064, -1477015.50419481424614787 947859.26077275548595935, -1477015.53112496319226921 947859.30622035439591855, -1477015.63153737201355398 947859.15003850637003779, -1477015.8134410073980689 947858.86702849948778749, -1477016.14561286033131182 947858.35050487564876676, -1477016.21729310508817434 947858.27944871853105724, -1477016.23541338578797877 947858.21072060940787196, -1477021.08374093542806804 947850.66884886415209621, -1477023.82911429018713534 947846.39819245657417923, -1477033.85934280976653099 947830.79540061485022306, -1477034.69958343170583248 947829.48815032979473472, -1477037.54546930571086705 947825.06131428841035813, -1477078.40050519746728241 947758.11568492045626044, -1477079.21621836279518902 947756.93222811596933752, -1477092.30156698566861451 947737.94530173391103745, -1477092.81394057534635067 947737.20204828691203147, -1477112.28553839540109038 947708.94881083781365305, -1477112.95448726811446249 947707.82851618598215282, -1477121.25337760685943067 947693.9284839624306187, -1477124.97664568177424371 947687.69246976636350155, -1477143.34180488344281912 947656.93267408665269613, -1477151.64249724289402366 947643.02972287149168551, -1477159.78100803890265524 947629.39854930946603417, -1477175.91887386050075293 947609.27772226231172681, -1477191.71846098732203245 947586.89030823286157101, -1477197.50634033465757966 947578.68904237821698189, -1477208.26768731256015599 947563.44051210395991802, -1477220.01243517454713583 947546.79860820365138352, -1477222.37427918682806194 947543.4519075786229223, -1477223.7308978762011975 947541.52976140624377877, -1477225.89291818742640316 947538.46606910019181669, -1477245.8410494748968631 947510.20010670728515834, -1477245.95547757600434124 947510.03805542760528624, -1477246.23879473679699004 947509.63662173179909587, -1477280.52617835439741611 947468.0576859035063535, -1477302.73453989624977112 947440.70395174436271191, -1477302.75756567530333996 947440.67561052564997226, -1477347.04123981297016144 947386.13156079198233783, -1477351.5327679393813014 947380.59916064026765525, -1477362.05084258317947388 947367.64410782989580184, -1477364.99193503917194903 947364.02149958477821201, -1477369.68849268765188754 947358.2369671476772055, -1477369.73144076229073107 947358.18392869317904115, -1477402.22291391575708985 947318.16410324047319591, -1477462.41049196501262486 947241.36334185139276087, -1477476.76416042982600629 947223.16887597227469087, -1477485.25526594719849527 947212.40595039573963732, -1477486.23446212965063751 947211.16461177065502852, -1477507.3139599459245801 947184.44486731151118875, -1477524.62844294705428183 947162.49746525101363659, -1477529.21968269138596952 947156.67763469461351633, -1477533.51839496474713087 947151.22866746981162578, -1477539.5490460847504437 947143.51191320735961199, -1477539.575675891013816 947143.51970699243247509, -1477548.01121921115554869 947132.67805370024871081, -1477554.9753152874764055 947123.59496255160775036, -1477586.0444962321780622 947083.07260535750538111, -1477597.26946222060360014 947068.43226482113823295, -1477608.68053655186668038 947053.5494115847395733, -1477646.524601761251688 946999.30535277235321701, -1477646.67687222361564636 946999.0871276471298188, -1477651.74915047152899206 946991.81677001342177391, -1477655.68836028617806733 946986.97836787637788802, -1477682.36192047712393105 946954.21587516472209245, -1477688.25792085728608072 946946.97396717977244407, -1477690.98917841492220759 946943.61921555735170841, -1477695.3211278913076967 946938.29851767153013498, -1477703.95018784422427416 946927.69953396008349955, -1477722.55211209878325462 946904.85112387500703335, -1477742.49904204276390374 946880.31158697442151606, -1477768.2853089370764792 946847.09875832195393741, -1477778.46280230744741857 946833.97584468743298203, -1477809.64941471163183451 946793.76378669450059533, -1477817.64466513483785093 946783.18376597808673978, -1477817.76860388345085084 946783.28751348401419818, -1477821.21846589329652488 946778.83618875383399427, -1477823.6209554011002183 946775.73631474061403424, -1477823.82768683042377234 946775.4694053374696523, -1477826.91424212767742574 946771.48681760253384709, -1477827.67158995289355516 946770.43294560944195837, -1477855.85213716700673103 946731.21570695715490729, -1477871.99280612030997872 946708.75364432332571596, -1477876.83082212950102985 946690.22275507973972708, -1477899.19936298439279199 946604.54539334529545158, -1477902.58515326608903706 946585.02960976026952267, -1477904.02196172531694174 946576.74735807487741113, -1477904.02696733130142093 946576.71871378005016595, -1477904.40088591864332557 946574.56381237658206373, -1477904.6012101776432246 946573.4086273709544912, -1477904.62834055069833994 946573.25245016592089087, -1477905.42363085318356752 946568.66814844589680433, -1477905.45726850419305265 946568.47391382500063628, -1477906.0343144906219095 946565.14844313054345548, -1477906.30571832275018096 946563.58383734396193177, -1477906.34616359462961555 946563.35073558066505939, -1477906.39341649296693504 946563.07805813744198531, -1477906.3957190690562129 946563.06510241900105029, -1477907.22714983415789902 946558.2722956653451547, -1477907.26789544313214719 946558.0376756798941642, -1477907.7755637641530484 946555.11130264867097139, -1477907.95766762341372669 946553.63870306627359241, -1477907.98059328622184694 946553.45297069963999093, -1477908.30956155410967767 946550.79138045199215412, -1477908.3336885659955442 946550.59653860598336905, -1477908.40186488814651966 946549.81524813827127218, -1477908.51849544909782708 946549.10167154611553997, -1477929.03796633519232273 946383.09553233219776303, -1477928.78067831159569323 946374.76493796776048839, -1477928.55332379299215972 946371.77268562524113804, -1477928.50056473608128726 946371.0790515432599932, -1477928.40515792765654624 946369.82285828003659844, -1477928.40475748269818723 946369.81850598531309515, -1477940.29326628451235592 946367.38385354785714298, -1477944.34980744821950793 946365.76864685502368957, -1477953.99971020454540849 946366.46693679422605783, -1478059.20958926132880151 946356.92084161238744855, -1478154.97739822417497635 946333.73760649736505002, -1478157.68022395204752684 946340.06573461089283228, -1478181.52441675262525678 946331.22208447905723006, -1478199.27028267504647374 946322.38926626602187753, -1478199.50294313114136457 946322.62530199531465769, -1478220.77655825717374682 946378.78777322929818183, -1478221.97720234072767198 946381.95755918242502958, -1478245.78004885511472821 946443.31493192829657346, -1478261.24305919767357409 946482.73231820727232844, -1478260.84991908818483353 946482.75590162712614983, -1478258.91965822130441666 946496.54785049532074481, -1478252.76556892483495176 946527.48263429978396744, -1478245.26807572180405259 946559.75785112415906042, -1478236.53690145281143486 946568.46915664616972208, -1478238.4718675883486867 946584.63203087309375405, -1478238.3886744542978704 946586.1472437079064548, -1478236.2912264266051352 946624.33497694204561412, -1478232.15489593776874244 946652.58649394265376031, -1478244.06372749456204474 946681.58278293593320996, -1478248.57577858585864305 946719.96939043037127703, -1478252.4960672240704298 946740.85277752671390772, -1478249.07573827705346048 946758.33811654907185584, -1478246.15176498517394066 946773.66025152825750411, -1478246.32435819692909718 946773.70448337949346751, -1478242.24989696475677192 946789.94334706920199096, -1478230.80248195584863424 946808.06596905097831041, -1478212.62963804346509278 946834.90886487625539303, -1478180.38223812519572675 946869.09316766762640327, -1478150.11395375500433147 946909.34416312875691801, -1478139.85046411328949034 946928.6078591231489554, -1478144.23637399566359818 946941.67260141635779291, -1478131.82217670255340636 946944.72542119526769966, -1478123.08539615874178708 946973.16814479720778763, -1478124.78303052391856909 946979.19179310125764459),(-1478072.8348422918934375 946951.6675226284423843, -1478062.97270194487646222 946946.10703957895748317, -1478063.24410577118396759 946946.28791519091464579, -1478063.46064818277955055 946946.43225129600614309, -1478072.8348422918934375 946951.6675226284423843, -1478106.22832521633245051 946970.31715075136162341, -1478106.26156241935677826 946970.13566773338243365, -1478072.8348422918934375 946951.6675226284423843),(-1478052.87690001679584384 946939.37962124519981444, -1478081.10389922792091966 946903.36039448843803257, -1478078.82715048687532544 946903.74502048012800515, -1478052.87690001679584384 946939.37962124519981444),(-1478182.37126477435231209 946754.03487488115206361, -1478160.27442808006890118 946750.65685830323491246, -1478160.69740158366039395 946752.26135035371407866, -1478182.37126477435231209 946754.03487488115206361))
```

[image: polygon_map]

Comment: judging by your coordinates, the following follows: the first, the polygon is not closed, and the second most likely you do not have a part of the southern and eastern coordinates, which should convert the list of coordinates into a polygon ...

Comment: Hi Cyril, thank you for your message. It seems like I had not copied the entire polygon coordinates, apologies for that. I have now edited and updated the GPS coordinates. Please let me know if it is now closed and includes the southern and eastern coordinates. Thank you

Comment: This time you downloaded the list of coordinates from several polygons, and from them it will be possible to create many polygons ...

Comment: Thanks Cyril, sorry I am relatively new in QGIS. Based on what you are saying, the updated list of GPS coordinates correspond to several polygons. However, I don't understand why I cannot split the polygon by feature if the wkt_geometry generates multiple polygons that are closed. Thanks for your help

Comment: Most likely the first polygon represents the polygon that you need, the second, third and fourth are polygon artifacts and you need to delete them ...

Answer (score 5):

You can't split "features" because there is only one feature in your polygon. So, I used **QuickWKT** QGIS plugin to visualize that complete polygon:

[image]

Near at bottom, there are several artifacts, however, three of them are holes (not features).

[image]

They can be eliminated with "Delete Ring" tool from Advanced Digitizing Toolbar (see following image).

[image]

Left artifact of above image is not a hole; as it can be observed at following image:

[image]

In this case you need to move or delete corresponding nodes.

Comment: Perfect, thank you xunilk! I'm now able to split the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to download the file with the * .shp resolution with the name poly and use it in your work,

I fixed the sidebar at the bottom of the polygon.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dyF69pgxOZMuNCrHOY9Zz_aWj9unLSsI/view?usp=sharing